# Responsive width css triangle with gradient

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build a triangle with a gradient that is 100% width of it's parent. The parent element will be in a row of three columns and will be responsive.
I did the the gradient part by making a solid color triangle and putting a transparent gradient over the top of it. The problem is that with this method I need to put a specific number for the width of the triangle. 
This is the method I'm using for the triangle

```
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 0 0 40px 300px;
border-color: transparent transparent red transparent;
```

I have not been able to find a way to make the triangle be 100% width of the parent container.

The end goal will be that the triangle will have a variant height, depending on which product is being looked at, but will always be 100% width of the parent container. This is an example of what my set up is like so far.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vOpQYo

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/josedvq/3HG6d/

Comment: Interesting way to do triangles. I'm not quite sure how that would work for having it be 100% width of the parent container and a variant height, however. It seems those are show more of less of a huge triangle.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a solid red triangle as a gradient also. This will be responsive if the angle is specified with keywords. And on top of it, the black/transparent gradient

```css
#test1 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}
#test2 {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
}
#test3 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
}
.test {
  display: inline-block;
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, black, transparent), linear-gradient(to top left, red 50%, black 50%);
  }
```

```html
<div class="test" id="test1"></div>
<div class="test" id="test2"></div>
<div class="test" id="test3"></div>
```